# Correct Way to Write a Custom Sleep

Tags: c++, optimization

I'm currently writing code for a simulator to sync with ROS time.

Essentially, the problem becomes "write a get_time and sleep that scales according to ROS time"? Doing this will allow no change to the codebase and just require linking to the custom get_time and sleep. `get_time` seems to work perfectly; however, I've been having trouble getting the sleep to run accurately.

My current design is like this (code attached at the bottom):

1. Thread calls sleep
2. Sleep will add the time when to unlock this thread (current_time + sleep_time) into a priority queue, and then wait on a condition variable.
3. A separate thread (let's call it watcher) will constantly loop and check for the top of the queue; if the top of the prio queue > current time, then it will notify_all on the condition variable and then pop the prio queue

However, it seems like the watcher thread is not accurate enough (I see discrepancies of 0~50ms), meaning the sleep calls make the threads sleep too long sometimes. I also visibly notice lag/jagged behavior in the simulator compared to if I were to replace the sleep with a usleep(1000*ms).

Unfortunately, I'm not too experienced at these types of designs, and I feel like there are lots of ways to optimize/rewrite this to make it run more accurately.
So my question is, are condition variables the right way? Am I even using them correctly? Here are some things I tried:

- reduce the number of unnecessary notify_all calls by having an array of condition variables and assigning them based on time like this: (ms/100)%256. The idea being that close together times will share the same cv because they are likely to actually wake up from the notify_all. This made the performance worse
- keep the threads and prio_queue pushing etc. but instead use usleep. I found out that the usleep will make it work so much better, which probably means the mutex, locking, and pushing/popping operations do not contribute to a noticeable amount of lag, meaning it must be in the condition variable part

---

Code:
Watcher (this is run on startup)

```
void watcher()
{
  while (true)
  {
    usleep(1);
    {
      std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(m_queue);
      if (prio_queue.empty())
        continue;
      if (get_time_in_ms() >= prio_queue.top())
      {
        cv.notify_all();
        prio_queue.pop();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Sleep

```
void sleep(int ms)
{
  int wakeup = get_time_in_ms() + ms;
  {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(m_queue);
    prio_queue.push(wakeup);
  }
  std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(m_time);
  cv.wait(lk, [wakeup] {return get_time_in_ms() >= wakeup;});
  lk.unlock();
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Sleep time is only guaranteed to be AT LEAST the amount of time you request. There is never a guarantee of EXACT sleeps. You would need to be running on an RTOS in order to reduce the amount of error, but I don't believe there is any system which can maintain exact sleeps accurately and consistently. Maybe introduction of a 1 PPS signal + interrupt would be a good method, but that adds some annoying hardware + software overhead.

Comment: but I do know for a fact the OS's usleep does much better than this version. It doesn't need to be perfect; just as good as how the OS does it